# How to call certain methods when application comes foreground in Android

Tags: java, android, background-foreground

I  tried to follow this https://stackoverflow.com/a/52217644/18210851 but this  method **ProcessLifecycleOwner.get().getLifecycle().addObserver(this)** is deprecated and requires deprecated gradle dependency. Is there a way I can call some method only once  when the application comes foreground.

Comment: [The Jetpack edition of `ProcessLifecycleOwner`](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/lifecycle/ProcessLifecycleOwner) is not deprecated.

Comment: @CommonsWare Could you please let me know about the gradle dependency it requires?

Comment: Today, use `implementation "androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-process:2.4.1"`.